# How to execute a script when I terminate a docker container

Tags: docker

I want when I type on my console:

```
docker ^a docker container^ stop
```

To execute a script before terminating. is that possible?

Comment: Do you want the script to execute inside the container or outside the container on the host?

Comment: Inside the container.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> The docker stop command attempts to stop a running container first by sending a SIGTERM signal to the root process (PID 1) in the container. If the process hasn't exited within the timeout period a SIGKILL signal will be sent.

In practice, that means that you have to define an ENTRYPOINT script, which will intercept (trap) the SIGTERM signal and execute any shutdown logic as appropriate.

A sample entrypoint script can look something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#Define cleanup procedure
cleanup() {
    echo "Container stopped, performing cleanup..."
}

#Trap SIGTERM
trap 'cleanup' SIGTERM

#Execute a command
"${@}" &

#Wait
wait $!
```

(shell signal handling, with respect to *wait*, is explained in a bit more detail [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146770/182018))

Note, that with the entrypoint above, the cleanup logic will only be executed if container is stopped explicitly, if you wish it to also run when the underlying process or command stops by itself (or fails), you can restructure it as follows.

```sh
...
...

#Trap SIGTERM
trap 'true' SIGTERM

#Execute command
"${@}" &

#Wait
wait $!

#Cleanup
cleanup
```

Comment: Note that ENTRYPOINTmust be in the _exec form_ to be run as PID 1:
ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"] [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

Comment: I have a script set as `ENTRYPOINT [ "myscript" ]`. The script is defined as suggested and has a trap for singals 1, 2, 9. But it seems the signal is not trapped when I stop the container... don't understand what I miss

Comment: How to get this working in systemd container? for eg. centos 7 based

Comment: However I try this, it exits immediately with code 0. Does base distro matter? I'm using alpine. I installed bash which isn't there by default.

Comment: Update: the problem is that "${@}" & does not create a process that lasts forever. I swapped it for less /etc/password which works but there has to be a cleaner way

Answer (score 2):

I worked way too long on getting this to work. Here is a solution that worked for me (based on the other response given):

*docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
    your_service:
        image: alpine
        entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "./shutdown_handler.sh"]
```

*shutdown_handler.sh*

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Waiting for signal..."
echo "pid=$$"

# Sleeping in the background seems to do the job
sleep infinity &
wait $!

# ADD YOUR CODE HERE
echo "Received arbitrary signal"
```

Comment: Doesn't works for me sorry..