# How to execute a command before removing a container with Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I need some help with this. I have created a container running a mysql database with Docker and I would like to know if it is possible make a SQL Dump before the container was removed.

Otherwise, if a dump cannot be made before the container is killed, the data stored in the DB will be lost.

Comment: This is a wrong way to persist your data even if there is such a mechanism to execute a pre-removing command. Use volumes instead, for both performance and data safety reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a script when I terminate a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451159/how-to-execute-a-script-when-i-terminate-a-docker-container)

Comment: @Yuankun , but if i make changes to the database, how i backup them before the container has died?