# Backup Mysql DB before docker-compose down

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have MySQL backup container which is doing DB backup every 1 hour, but I only need to do a backup just before `docker-compose down`. Is it possible at all? As I understand this should be some kind of hook "Before Down" "After Start".

I want to use something like this, but this should be done automatically just right before container shutdown:

```
docker exec MYSQL_CONTAINER_ID /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=root DATABASE > backup.sql
```

**UPDATE**

What I've done so far is created down.sh script inside this script I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

docker exec test1-mysql sh -c 'exec mysqldump --databases local -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"' > "$CURRENT_DIR/docker/data/backup/local.sql"

docker-compose down
```

Seams legit for me, jsut need to figure out how can I pass mysql container name to this script as variable. Here container name is test1-mysql. I vould like to grab this value from docker-compose.yml. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from post [How to execute a script when I terminate a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451159/how-to-execute-a-script-when-i-terminate-a-docker-container?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

TL;DR: docker stop sends a SIGTERM to your container's ENTRYPOINT pid. You could modify your ENTRYPOINT script to trap SIGTERM and do a backup then or other cleanup work.

Comment: Didn't really get. What if I using docker-compose

Comment: It shouldnt make any difference as docker-compose is leveraging the underlying docker commands. Based on your description, you have an existing backup container. That container's ENTRYPOINT script would need to be modified to catch a SIGTERM and do the backup. You would need access to the Docker file which built the image so that you could modify it.

Comment: Ok, but that post doesn't explain how to RUN something before container stop. It just explain how container being stopped. It's doesn't explain how to define entry script in docker-compose to backup database for example, as I need to run backup inside container, I can't find any configurations example for this simple task.

Comment: This Dockerfile for mysql https://github.com/dockerfile/mysql/blob/master/Dockerfile#L30 runs 'mysqld_safe' as the default process. The idea is that you would replace that with a script which 1) defines the SIGTERM trap logic for your last backup and 2) runs 'mysqld_safe' . Your would then build the image with docker build, then reference it with docker-compose.yaml