# Docker. Laravel. Clear cache after "down"ing containers

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, laravel-artisan

I'm using docker-compose for running my Laravel 5.6 app.

I need to automatically run `php artisan clear:cache` before `down`'ing my container.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451159/how-to-execute-a-script-when-i-terminate-a-docker-container).

Comment: @Tpojka I saw it, but I already have an already running `supervisor` there :)

Comment: So, just put one more line there: `cd /path/to/laravel/root && php artisan clear:cache`. Wouldn't that work?