# Capturing docker-compose shutdown events in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I've been trying to capture shutdown commands in my node.js application so I can tidy up connections before killing the app.

In production, my app uses docker swarm, and I can see SIGTERM being triggered through my:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function() {});
```

However, in my dev environment, I'm using `docker-compose run` and `docker-compose down`, which doesn't seem to trigger my **SIG*** captures (I have a local version of rabbitMQ running which the **SIG** events publish too before shutting down).

I'm running an **ubuntu:bionic** image in my Dockerfile and in my docker-compose file I have **init: true**.  My Docker engine is *18.09.2* and compose is *1.23.2* with **version: "3.7"** at the top of my compose file.

These are all my capture events in my index.js:

```
process.on('exit', () => {
  reporter.ossEvent('APP STOPPED exit');
  shutdown();
});

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  reporter.ossEvent('APP STOPPED SIGINT');
  shutdown();
});

process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
  reporter.ossEvent('APP STOPPED SIGTERM');
  shutdown();
});

process.on('SIGUSR1', () => {
  reporter.ossEvent('APP STOPPED SIGUSR2');
  shutdown();
});

process.on('SIGUSR2', () => {
  reporter.ossEvent('APP STOPPED SIGUSR2');
  shutdown();
})
```

Comment: May this explanation will be usefull for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451159/how-to-execute-a-script-when-i-terminate-a-docker-container

Answer (score 2):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

_kill_procs() {
  kill -TERM $node
}

# Relay quit commands to processes
trap _kill_procs SIGTERM SIGINT

dumb-init -- node ./build/index.js $@ &
node=$!

#sleep infinity

echo 'Starting node process now'

wait $node
```

The above piece of code is to listen to SIGTERM AND SIGKILL and kill node