# How to print to terminal from a service (reacting to SIGINT/SIGTERM) when CTRL+C-ing docker compose?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, sigint, sigterm

I have a service (python in that example) that prints something on `SIGINT`/`SIGTERM`.

`printer.py`:

```py
import signal
import sys
import threading

def runner(stop_event):
    while not stop_event.wait(1):
        print('Hi.', flush=True)

stop_event = threading.Event()

def signal_handler(*_):
    stop_event.set()
    print('Bye.', flush=True)
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

runner_thread = threading.Thread(target=runner, args=(stop_event,))
runner_thread.start()
runner_thread.join()
```

When running normally in the terminal and pressing CTRL+C, it works fine, i.e., the `Bye.` message is printed:

```
$ python3 printer.py 
Hi.
Hi.
^CBye.
```

However when running with Docker compose and CTRL+C-ing it, `Bye.` is never shown.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7
ADD printer.py .
CMD [ "python", "printer.py" ]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  printer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Terminal interaction:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "compose_print_term_default" with the default driver
Creating compose_print_term_printer_1 ... done
Attaching to compose_print_term_printer_1
printer_1  | Hi.
printer_1  | Hi.
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping compose_print_term_printer_1 ... done
```

What can be done to make the `Bye.` visible?

Comment: Take a look to this Question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451159/how-to-execute-a-script-when-i-terminate-a-docker-container

Comment: @Wie Thanks. But printing `Bye.` is just an example. In reality the service calculates some statistics of its working and prints a summary from it. So it can not simply be done in a wrapping shell script as explained in the answer to the question you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with docker compose, already known for a few years:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/592