# Shutdown Script is not working in Compute Enginer with docker exec command

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I am running 10 docker containers in my GCE instance as a startup script. In the shutdown script I am trying to execute a script inside the running containers and hence for each container I am executing something like this:

```
sudo docker exec $CONTAINERID /bin/bash -c "sh /home/user/shut-application-script.sh"
```

However it seems the docker container is terminated prematurely well before and VM shuts/powers off without executing the script inside the container as I wanted. I get the below errors:

*level=info msg="Container XXXX failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
level=info msg="Daemon shutdown complete"
level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
[[32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
systemd: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
GCEMetadataScripts[12864]: ****** GCEMetadataScripts: shutdown-script: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Stopping containerd container runtime...
systemd: Stopping containerd container runtime...*

Hence please let me know how I can gracefully shutdown my Compute Engine VM which can wait until my script get executed inside the containers.
Thanks.

Comment: 1) Figure out why your container shutdown script is not completing or not completing fast enough. 2) You will most likely need to shut down the containers in parallel and not sequentially. 3) Your question only has an error message without any code/scripts.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, 1) the container script takes 20sec approx to execute an application de-registration for each container. 2) can you please let me know how to run parallel docker exec commands for multiple containers? 3)updated
thanks

Comment: How do you run shell scripts inside non-container processes; do you need a debugging tool like `docker exec` as part of your normal operating process?  `docker stop` the container will send it a SIGTERM which should be enough to trigger its normal shutdown sequence.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I am currently executing {docker exec} in a for loop hence its being executed for each container sequentially. Each loop executes per container script to de-register an application and then shuts down the container which takes around 10-15 sec (per container).

Comment: As a workaround, you can trigger the execution of the script at the termination of the docker container using `docker stop`, as @DavidMaze suggested. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41451517/11199996)  you can see how it can be done.