# Graceful shutdown in a docker compose service

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I would like to be able to execute code before service start and shutdown. Ideally, I would like a solution that is applicable to any service. For the sake of this question, let's assume I want to run `echo up` before the service starts and `echo down` before the service is requested to shutdown, without needing to know any specifics about how the service is defined.

```yaml
x-lifetime-hooks:: &lifetime-hooks
  # PART I DONT KNOW

services:
  foo:
    <<: *foo_definition # intentionally not shown
    <<: *lifetime-hooks
```

Telling me that it's not possible is equally valuable information to me as a working solution, meaning I will mark it as an answer. If the general, reusable solution I described is not possible, then consider this specific service definition.

```yaml
services
  tailscale:
    image: tailscale/tailscale
    hostname: tailscale
    environment:
      TS_AUTH_KEY: ${TS_AUTH_KEY}
    cap_add:
      - net_admin
    command: |
      /bin/sh -c 'sh -s <<EOF
      tailscaled --tun=userspace-networking &
      until tailscale up --ssh --authkey=$$TS_AUTH_KEY; do sleep 0.1; done
      sleep infinity
      EOF'
```

Where I would like to run `tailscale down` on service shutdown, ideally avoiding having to create a Dockerfile.

Comment: You can try something like what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451159/how-to-execute-a-script-when-i-terminate-a-docker-container)

Comment: In the example you show, can you run `tailscaled` as a foreground process as the container command; `command: tailscaled --tun=userspace-networking`?  More generally, can you launch these supporting processes as separate containers?  What happens if you don't stop the process before the container cleanup phase happens?

Comment: @AbhishekS doesn't work

Comment: @DavidMaze I think I could somehow figure how to work around the tailscale service but I am interested in general solution as there are many questions here and elsewhere about basically the same thing. The tailscale example was really just for more context now I think the question would be better without it.

Comment: There isn't a generic notion of "hook" in Docker.  If your use case is around running a second process, a second container is usually a better approach.  You can do setup steps in an entrypoint wrapper script; there's not a good generic way to do cleanup steps.